# Python- request.post login credentials for website

Tags: python, request

So I am trying to write this python script and add it to my Windows Task Scheduler to be executed every time I log on my Work Machine. The script should open a webpage and post my login info.

```
import webbrowser
import os


url = 'www.example.com'
webbrowser.open(url)
import requests
url = 'www.example.com'
values = ["'username': username","'password': 'somepass'"]

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print r.content
```

When I run the script it opens my browser and lands on the page I want it to however Nothing is posted and I get these errors on my IDE;

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\myscript.py", line 20, in <module>
r = requests.post(url, data=values)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\api.py", line 110, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 395, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\models.py", line 302, in prepare
self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\models.py", line 462, in prepare_body
body = self._encode_params(data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\models.py", line 95, in _encode_params
for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data):
 ValueError: too many values to unpack*`
```

Comment: You should pass a dict as an argument values:
values = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'somepass'}

Comment: Formatting tip : you don't need backticks to wrap a block of code

Comment: I made the dictionary however still get the same errors. Its not posting my values onto the webpage. I am still very new to python and have been researching this issue for awhile now with no luck. It appears to be with the request module, havent used it before so im sure thats the root of my errors.

Answer (score 1):

That is what your dict should look like

```
values = {'username': 'username','password': 'somepass'}
```

Comment: import webbrowser
import os



url = 'www.example.com'
webbrowser.open(url)
import requests
url = 'www.example.com'
values = {'User name': username,'Password': 'pass}

r = requests.get(url, data=values)
print r.content

Comment: Ok I changed my dictionary my scripts runs now with no errors, it opens the landing page yet no data is inputted in the credentials fields. There is also "OK" button i normally would hit to execute the login. but no data is inputted is inputted regardless. again I am new